# Modify Specific UIWebView code to have an address bar similar to Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview

I've built an app using PhoneGap and am using its InAppBrowser plugin.  For the iOS platform, the InAppBrowser is implemented using an UIWebView.  The "address bar" is a simple UILabel so it is basically read-only from the user's perspective.

I'd like to extend the plugin to have a simple functioning address bar.  You know, let the user type in new URLs and show little inline refresh and go buttons.  Basically like a regular browser such as Mobile Safari, Chrome, etc.

I know 99 programming languages but Objective-C isn't one. :(  Mostly, I don't have experience working with the iOS framework.

These assume too much for me to take action on:

[iOS WebView with an Address Bar](http://normansoven.com/ios-webview/#.U7W2wI1dU1c)

[Adding a header view to a UIWebView similar to Safari and Articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483028/adding-a-header-view-to-a-uiwebview-similar-to-safari-and-articles)

I'd like to just modify the [PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) iOS source itself so I can keep the plugin hooks it provides to my PhoneGap app's javascript.

Here are the two relevant files:

[CDVInAppBrowser.h and CDVInAppBrowser.m on Github](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/tree/master/src/ios)

Hopefully this is a welcome challenge to some one already proficient in Objective-C & iOS?

Or maybe you can accelerate me in making the changes myself?

Thanks!!

So you can see what the current UIWebView (with UILabel for Address) looks like:
[image]